# Parsing badly formed XML with BeautifulSoup without converting tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup is pretty good to fix badly formed XML very simply:

```py
import bs4
value = unicode(bs4.BeautifulSoup(value, "xml"))
```

But when dealing with this kind of XML:

```xml
<draw:image xlink:href="Pictures/image.png" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad"/>
```

It gives me:

```xml
<image actuate="onLoad" href="Pictures/image.png" show="embed" type="simple"/>
```

I want to keep it raw! How to tell BeautifulSoup not be too smart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking precisely at the whole document, I saw that some namespaces definitions were not present anymore. After adding them, the desired behavior was reached.

Comment: Could you explain more about how you fixed this? I don't quite understand. How did you use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: For instance, the "xlink" namespace definition was missing. I had it to the source document:

`<office:document-styles xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`

No change in BeautifulSoup code.